# Create two processes when another terminal window is opened?

Tags: c, terminal, multiprocessing

The topic might sound weird, but here's what I want to achieve:

1. In Terminal A, type command line as following:

   ```
   ./create proA
   ```
2. The first process proA is created. It outputs something like

   ```
   This is process A.
   ```
3. Open another terminal window (called Terminal B). In Terminal B, type the following line:

   ```
   ./create proB
   ```
4. The second process proB is created. It outputs:

   ```
   This is process B.
   ```

UPDATED:
I'm trying to create two processes that communicate with each other. Before going into more details, I just want to try if I can create another process that has some relationship with first process when another terminal window is opened.

Is it possible to achieve something like this? If so, can someone give any tip for how to start in c? Thanks!

Comment: What you're describing is a program that prints "This is process X" where X depends on the string you pass to the program. I don't think that's what you're trying to do, so you must explain in more detail what that is.

Comment: @simon I just updated with more details. Thanks.

Comment: What you're looking for is inter process communication. There exist many API's that enable processes to communicate among eachother (e.g. LCM, see http://code.google.com/p/lcm/). However, I've hardly got any experience on that matter and others can give you a more qualified answer.

Comment: please explain type of **relationship** between these two processes.

Comment: the relationship can be siblings or parent-child

Answer (score 2):

The terminals don't matter for inter process communication. There are so many ways to communicate between processes that it doesn't make sense to highlight any of them here.

About having a own terminal for each process. Well:

```
(xterm -e "${COMMANDLINE1}" &) ; (xterm -e "${COMMANDLINE2}" &)
```

Comment: this appropriate if you want to see output

Comment: @HDDimon: Sorry, but I can't make any sense of your comment.

Comment: excuse me) i meant that, if you want to see all output information of processes in terminal, this method will be appropriate in this situation

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see only errors, you should use:

```
 ./process > /dev/null 2>&1
```

if you did't understood 2>&1, read below)

possible numbers:

```
0 — STDIN, 1 — STDOUT and 2 — STDERR
```

that means, all std errors will be printed in std out.